# How to override a form default value with parsed typoscript

Tags: php, forms, typo3, hook, typoscript

I created a hook (with a function `afterBuildingFinished`) that take a string and parse it into typoscript.
Now I want to take that typoscript to override a form (yaml) default value with. I don't understand how to ''process'' the typoscript. Like, i'm missing the step after get the typoscript parsed.

This is a part of my code :

```
public function afterBuildingFinished(RenderableInterface $renderable): void {

   #some code here ...

   #My parsing code :
   $parseObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScriptParser::class);
   $parseObj->parse($stringToParse);
   $TSparse = $parseObj->setup; #this is use to access the parse typoscript

   #Now, what do I do after?
}
```

My purpose is to prefill renderable of a form with user info via a typoscript string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and needed to change a little bit my code.

Here is the new one :

```
public function afterBuildingFinished(RenderableInterface $renderable): void {

   #some code here ...

   #My parsing code :
   $parseObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScriptParser::class);
   $parseObj->parse($stringToParse);

   #This process the typoscript
   #$value stock user info for a X renderable
   $cObject =  GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get(ContentObjectRenderer::class);
   $value = $cObject->cObjGet($parseObj->setup);

   #Some code to set the default value of the renderable
}
```

To answer my question: after parsing the code, I need to process the typoscript with [cObject](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Index.html) and then set the default value of the renderable with classic setDefaultValue() functions.